# Typescript key as string in object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have interface

```
interface ITest {
    [key: string]: {
        [key: string]: ITest;
        access: number[];
    };
}
```

But I get error

Property 'access' of type 'number[]' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'ITest'.

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures: While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match their return type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```js
interface ITest {
    [key: string]: ITestEntry;
}

interface ITestEntry {
    [key: string]: ITest | number[] | undefined;
    access: number[];
}
```